# Chrome extension content scripts and iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm tryng to make an extension for google chrome that does this things:

Run when loading www.example.com
example.com has an iframe to another site, i need to get access to a link from this iframe (this is rapidshare, I need to grab the downloadlink)

So far so good, but..

Then I need the extension to inform the link url to example.com for further processing.

Any ideas o directions??

I've read http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication but can't make it work...

Comment: The iframe injection part is addressed in this [partial duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288202/inject-javascript-in-an-iframe-using-chrome-extension).

Answer (score 56):

You need to inject 2 content scripts:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*"],
      "js": ["example.js"]
    },{
      "matches": ["http://www.rapidshare.com/*"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["rapidshare.js"]
    }
]
```

In order to transfer the link from one script to another you need to communicate through background page:

**rapidshare.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({url: "link"});
```

**background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, request);
    sendResponse({});
});
```

**example.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("received url:", request.url);
    sendResponse({});
});
```

Comment: Thank you Serg, I got no time to test it right now, but I'll tell you how it goes! Thanks again

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out that different scripts could be loaded into different pages via the matches property!

Comment: what does all_frames do?

Comment: all_frames means - match applies for iFrames as well as top frames

Answer (score 4):

iframe is a separate document for the browser, that's why you can use chrome extension and integrate it directly into iframe. You need just mention URL of the iframe in chrome extension manifest file. We use integration of some menus and toolbars of our chrome extension apps into iframes. It works.

There is a nice article as additional info for Chrome Extensions and iFrames http://www.natewillard.com/blog/chrome/javascript/iframes/2015/10/20/chrome-communication/

Answer (score 0):

v3: serg's answer, what worked for me

```json
"manifest_version": 3,
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.rapidshare.com/*"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["insideIframe-content.js"]
    }
]
```

**background.js:**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(url)
})
```

**insideIframe-content.js:**

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(url)
```